# Personalizar - traducir - los controles de una tabla generada con package DT

Tags: r

¿Es posible personalizar (traducir) los controles de una tabla generada con el package DT?

Show 5 entries
Search:
Showing 1 to 5 of 505 entries
All (para filtrado)
Previous
Next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es completamente posible. Debes usar una lista de opciones en la llamada a `renderDataTable()`. Yo generé una lista previamente para usar las mismas opciones en varias tablas.

```r
# Opciones personalizadas para DT
options_DT <- list(
  pageLength = 10,
  lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 40),
  language = list(
    emptyTable = "Cliente no tiene registros en esta sección",
    zeroRecords = "Cliente no existe. Buscar con otros datos o Agregar cliente",
    infoEmpty = "Datos no coinciden con ningún registro.",
    infoFiltered = "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    lengthMenu = "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    info = "Mostrando _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    search = "Buscar:",
    paginate = list(previous = "Anterior",
                    'next' = "Siguiente")
  )
)
```

### Para uso en una `shiny` app

```r
output$mi_tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    mi_df
    
  },
  options = options_DT
  )
```

### Para otros usos

```r
datatable(mi_df, options = options_DT)
```

Puedes revisar la documentación para más detalles. https://datatables.net/reference/option/language

Comment: Perfecto, sí se puede, lo he utilizado como ```options_DT <- list()```, ```df %>% datatable(options = options_DT)```

Comment: ok, edito la respuesta para mostrarlo. asumí que era para usarlo con `shiny`

Comment: Lo único que no he conseguido localizar es el texto "all" de los filtros. Buscado en https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Spanish.html